# Center text in a cell programmatically: works with single line texts but not for longer

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I created a table in PowerPoint, and I want to center the text horizontally in each cell.
I used **MsoHorizontalAnchor.msoAnchorCenter**.

It works well if text is short and in a sigle line but if the text is long, it displays in more than 1 line and is doesn't centered.
The code:

```
myShape.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "shortOK";
myShape.Table.Cell(1, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Long text is not displayed centered";

myShape.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoVerticalAnchor.msoAnchorMiddle;                 
myShape.Table.Cell(1, 2).Shape.TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoVerticalAnchor.msoAnchorMiddle;

myShape.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.HorizontalAnchor = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoHorizontalAnchor.msoAnchorCenter;
myShape.Table.Cell(1, 2).Shape.TextFrame.HorizontalAnchor = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoHorizontalAnchor.msoAnchorCenter;
```

Do you know how to keep text centered if displayed in more than 1 ligne ?

Answer (score 6):

I would use this documentation, "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.paragraphformat.alignment". The TextRange in interop has something called, "PPParagraphAlignment.ppAlignCenter", such as:

```
 textrange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = PpParagraphAlignment.ppAlignCenter;
```